# Obtain data from dynamically incremented IDs in JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a quick question about JQuery. I have dynamically generated paragraphs with id's that are incremented. I would like to take information from that page and bring it to my main page. Unfortunately I am unable to read the dynamically generated paragraph IDs to get the values. I am trying this:

```
var Name = ((data).find("#Name" + id).text());
```

The ASP.NET code goes like this:

```
Dim intI As Integer = 0
```

For Each Item As cItem in alProducts1
 Dim pName As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("p") 
    pName.id = "Name" & intI.toString() pName.InnerText = Item.Name controls.Add(pName) intI += 1 
Next

Those name values are the values I want...Name1, name2, name3 and I want to get them individually to put in their own textbox... I'm taking the values from the ASP.NET webpage and putting them into an AJAX page.

Comment: Can you post a little more of the code and the html you are working against?

Comment: sure thing...code added. Unfortunately it hasn't formatted well as ASP.NET code. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I found the solution today however:

var Name = ($(data).find('#Name' + id.toString()).text());

I forgot the .toString() part and that seems to have made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear about your exact requirement but you can get the IDs of elements with [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method of jQuery, here is an example:

```
alert($('selector').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all the elements with the incrementing ids, right?

```
// this will select all the elements
// which id starts with 'Name'
(data).find("[id^=Name]")
```

Comment: Forgive me for not writing things down so well. I want to find individual Id's. I.e. certain paragraphs will have different information in them which I will use to fill several textboxes and labels. I want to find the information based on the incrementing ID number to fill the web-form.

Comment: but your idea will find all id's that begin with the id name. I want id name1 to go into a one textbox, then name2 to go in another. So I want to take their values individually, instead of all together. 

It should look like this:

var Name = ((data).find("#Name" + id).text());

then I'll increment id (so id++;)
var Name1 = ((data).find("#Name" + id).text());

otherwise they come together in an array and I can get the values separated to put in their own inputboxes and labels.